# Scaling a column with for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to scale all the values of a column of a dataframe with a function. This is the function so far:

```
def scale0_1(cname):
     temp = array(cname)
     for i in range(len(temp)):
         value = temp[i]-min(temp)/(max(temp)-min(temp))
         temp[i] = value
     return pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

Here is a sample column to test the function with:

```
samplecolumn = pd.DataFrame([7.0, 15.8, 19.4, 11.4])
```

However, when I use the function with a column of a data frame (any numeric column should work), it just returns the original values, doing nothing. There is no error message. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I would be very grateful for any help :)

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Looks like you're looking for https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_normalize_column/

Comment: What is `cname`? If it is the column name, what is `array(cname)` supposed to do?

Comment: Can't replicate your problem. `scale0_1(samplecolumn)` -> `6.4, 15.3, ... != samplecolumn`.

Comment: The post has no MCVE and the problem OP claims to exist cannot be replicated. Therefore, none of the answers can address the question why OP's code is not working, but merely present alternatives. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.interp`

```
a=df[0].values

np.interp(a, (a.min(), a.max()), (0, +1))
Out[36]: array([0.        , 0.70967742, 1.        , 0.35483871])
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. I'd also mention for OP's benefit that you can assign an array directly to a series, i.e.. `df['B'] = np.interp(...)`.

Comment: Thank you - didn't know this existed!

Comment: @cholz yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

With pandas dataframes you can apply operations to entire columns. This allows you to do something like this:

```
def scale0_1(cname):
    scale_factor = min(cname) / (max(cname) - min(cname))
    return cname - scale_factor
```

This also allows you to keep the data in a pandas Series or DataFrame through the whole operation and avoids the added complexity of converting it into an array and back.

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I didn't know pandas had that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Where possible, you should use a vectorised approach rather than iterating rows explicitly. For example, you can calculate a column's maximum and minimum. Then, when performing operations with series, the calculations are automatically vectorised.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7.0, 15.8, 19.4, 11.4]})

col_min = df['A'].min()
col_max = df['A'].max()

df['B'] = (df['A'] - col_min) / (col_max - col_min)
```

This is a frequent task, so you will find it exists in other 3rd party libraries. For example, using `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
df['B'] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df['A'])
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

      A         B
0   7.0  0.000000
1  15.8  0.709677
2  19.4  1.000000
3  11.4  0.354839
```

Comment: Thank you - didn't know this existed!